# Which is the default transaction manager the @Transactional uses?

Tags: spring, transactions

We have configured multiple transaction managers:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager3" />

<bean id="transactionManage1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager2"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManage3"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory3" />
</bean>
```

However,I don't see a name of transaction manager specified in @Transactional annotation in a service class. I am wondering which transaction manager will be used? The code is working and it looks like it used the first one - "transactionManager1" by default. Do I miss something?

Comment: Have you not answered your own question? If you need to, you can set the _value_ attribute of _@Transactional_ annotation to the name of the specific tx manager you require.

Comment: I know we can specify the value but my question is how it works if we don't specify the value. It seems using the first tx manager although I cannot find which book/tutorial saying like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering which transaction manager will be used?

The behaviour there is probably undefined, but it's most likely to use whichever `<tx:annotation-driven>` comes first in the context.

There's no reason you should need to do this. If you need fine-grained control over which tx manager to use, then you need to do it programmatically using something like `TransactionTemplate`. The `@Transactional` annotation is a convenience, but isn't as flexible as using the underlying API directly.

Comment: Yes. That is what I want to know. I cannot find the evidence anywhere to support my guess (use the first configured tx mgr if we don't specify the value in the annotation.